# Return debug information from Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm writing a Java application to run a MapReduce job on Hadoop. I've set up some local variables in my mapper/reducer classes but I'm not able to return the information to the main Java application. For example, if I set up a variable inside my Mapper class:

```
private static int nErrors = 0;
```

Each time I process a line from the input file, I increment the error count if the data is not formatted correctly. Finally, I define a get function for the errors and call this after my job is complete:

```
public static int GetErrors()
{
    return nErrors;
}
```

But when I print out the errors at the end:

```
System.out.println("Errors = " + UPMapper.GetErrors());
```

This always returns "0" no matter what I do! If I start with `nErrors = 12;`, then the final value is `12`. Is it possible to get information from the MapReduce functions like this?

#### UPDATE

Based on the suggestion from `Binary Nerd`, I implemented some Hadoop counters:

```
// Define this enumeration in your main class
public static enum MyStats
{
    MAP_GOOD_RECORD,
    MAP_BAD_RECORD
}
```

Then inside the mapper:

```
if (SomeCheckOnTheInputLine())
{
    // This record is good
    context.getCounter(MyStats.MAP_GOOD_RECORD).increment(1);
}
else
{
    // This record has failed in some way...
    context.getCounter(MyStats.MAP_BAD_RECORD).increment(1);
}
```

Then in the output stream from Hadoop I see:

```
MAP_BAD_RECORD=11557
MAP_GOOD_RECORD=8676
```

Great! But the question still stands, how do I get those counter values back into the main Java application?

Comment: Where is your code for increment ?

Comment: You should use hadoop counters for this i would think.

Comment: @javaguy: Either `nErrors++;` directly or through a `public static void SetError()` which does the same thing.